# javamail getcontent() doesn't work

Tags: java, android, jakarta-mail

I can't see the contents of the message.
The application exploits in the getcontent() method.

here is the code

```
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            try {
                //create properties field
                Properties properties = new Properties();

                properties.put("mail.pop3.host", "255.255.255.255");
                properties.put("mail.pop3.port", "110");
                properties.put("mail.pop3.starttls.enable", "false");
                Session emailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);

                //create the POP3 store object and connect with the pop server
                Store store = emailSession.getStore("pop3");

                store.connect("255.255.255.255", "popo@midominio.com", "ok");

                //create the folder object and open it
                Folder emailFolder = store.getFolder("INBOX");
                emailFolder.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);

                Message[] messages = emailFolder.getMessages();

                for (int i = 0, n = messages.length; i < n; i++) {

                Message message = messages[i];


                //here is the killer line   
                    Multipart mp = (Multipart) message.getContent();

                }

                emailFolder.close(false);
                store.close();                
                } catch (NoSuchProviderException e) {
                } catch (MessagingException e) {
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }

           return null;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Test the contentType before reading the message.
You can see an example on this link:
[JavaMail API - Fetching Emails](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javamail_api/javamail_api_fetching_emails.htm)

Comment: i just made it, the conten is multipart/mixed

Comment: Once you as tested, you can get the number of parts of your multipart 
then iterate over to find part that is attachment or part that is message content for example.

In addition you can look at [JavaMailTM API Design Specification](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail-1-149769.pdf) , hoping i'll help you..